# Hiberante 3.0 inner join for two different entity with forigen key

Tags: hibernate

I am new with this. Please help me.

My controller for listing  looks like this:
`@RequestMapping(value="/possalesList.htm",method=RequestMethod.GET)
            public String PosSalesList(@ModelAttribute("possales")PSales sales,@RequestParam(value = "salesItemID", required = false)Integer salesItemID,ModelMap model)
            {
                List<POSSalesItem> posSalesItemList = posSalesDao.listSalesItem();
                model.addAttribute("possalesList", posSalesItemList);

            return "possalesList";
            }`

My hibernateDaoimpl looks like this:
`@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    @Transactional(readOnly=true)
    public List<POSSalesItem> listSalesItem() { 
        return (List<POSSalesItem>)getHibernateTemplate().find("select POSSales.posSalesId , POSSalesItem.itemName from POSSales inner join POSSalesItem on POSSales.posSalesId=POSSalesItem.posSalesId");
    }`

My inner join looks like this:
`select POSSales.posSalesId , POSSalesItem.itemName from POSSales inner join POSSalesItem on POSSales.posSalesId=POSSalesItem.posSalesId`

the foreign key is created successfully in mysql.

what i am doing is i am listing posSalesId from POSSales table and other columns from POSSalesItem .for that purpose i have written this join query but its showing some error.

I want to make the inner join on the column posSalesId, but I get these errors:

org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateQueryException: unexpected token: on near line 1, column 111 [select POSSales.posSalesId , POSSalesItem.itemName from com.jewellery.entity.POSSales inner join POSSalesItem on POSSales.posSalesId=POSSalesItem.posSalesId]; nested exception is org.hibernate.hql.ast.QuerySyntaxException: unexpected token: on near line 1, column 111 [select POSSales.posSalesId , POSSalesItem.itemName from com.jewellery.entity.POSSales inner join POSSalesItem on POSSales.posSalesId=POSSalesItem.posSalesId]
    org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.SessionFactoryUtils.convertHibernateAccessException(SessionFactoryUtils.java:660)
    org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateAccessor.convertHibernateAccessException(HibernateAccessor.java:412)
    org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate.doExecute(HibernateTemplate.java:411)
    org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate.executeWithNativeSession(HibernateTemplate.java:374)

Comment: You should add the actual hibernate code to your post if you want help with this, it seems you only posted your generated SQL

Comment: Your question is unreadable. Take some time to format it correctly.

Comment: @RasmusFranke can u help me nw...i have posted the controller and hibernate part also.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your HQL syntax `inner join POSSalesItem on POSSales.posSalesId=POSSalesItem.posSalesId` is malformed.

The correct syntax is (no `select` necessary)

```
from POSSales s inner join s.POSSalesItemList
```

The join condition you have to implement in the mapping (or annotations) where you tell  which class the members of POSSalesItemList are and what the key column (join column) is. For this have a look into the hibernate documentation, [one-to-many association with annotations](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/annotations/3.5/reference/en/html_single/#d0e2177).

Comment: brother ,i have two entity name as POSSales and POSSalesItem.in POSSales posSalesId is primary key ,and posSalesId is foreign key POSSalesItem.now i want to select POSSales entity one or two values and list them in a form view. if u want to have a look at my foreign key relationship ill show u.